# Invoking a PHP method from Java

Tags: java, php

I need to invoke a PHP method from java. Can I do that with request dispatcher?

Comment: I don't think, anyone can answer this question without any further information. Please describe your development environment!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling PHP function from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748137/calling-php-function-from-java)

Comment: since this is the authorative question marked to many duplicates (such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13748137/calling-php-function-from-java), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897070/how-can-i-run-php-code-within-a-java-application) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614995/calling-php-from-java)), the question should not be closed as not a real question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a handy way to invoke a PHP method from within a Java application.

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php <your script name>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to make a separate request as though it was to an external site, but that will essentially be a full web request. There is no way to call a single PHP function from within Java unless you've got a PHP interpreter in your JVM, which seems highly unlikely.

You probably want to write the PHP side like you would write for an AJAX interface (using [JSON](http://json.org) or some loosely defined XML) or a SOAP interface.

Comment: call over http is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

The request dispatcher is only meant to forward to (or include) another web resources in your J2EE web app.

If you want to bring user to a PHP page from a J2EE webapp, issue a redirect.

If you want to process results of request to a php page in your J2EE webapp, try HttpURLConnection or the like.