# JavaBridge PHP-Java How to call a java class from a php file

Tags: java, syntax, php-java-bridge

I set up a JavaBridge api over a Tomcat server. All right, it works well.

But I've got a specific need, I have Java classes to call from PHP and I haven't found any documentation about this.

Each java class is in a different file, do I have to include the files in a xml manifest or something like that ?
Classes do have to be compiled or not ? (I think so but..)

Typically I would like to do :

```
<?php
    import com.test.Test;

    $obj=new Test();
?>
```

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT (solved):**

http://www.dsl.uow.edu.au/~sk33/php5java.htm

Tutorial very interesting.

1. compile the java class and put it in a jar and thinking about the
   folders due to packages.
2. Put the jar into the WEB-INF\lib folder
3. Call the class

> ```
> <?php
>   require_once("java/Java.inc");
>   //java_require("Test.jar"); //Deprecated !!!
>   $obj=new Java("com.test.Test");
>   echo $obj->getMessage();
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614995/calling-php-from-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do something like:

```
 <?php
    $obj = new Java("com.test.Test");
 ?>
```