# How can I run PHP code within a Java application?

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling PHP from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614995/calling-php-from-java)

I was wondering how I could run PHP code within Java. Using the ScriptEngine, I am able to run JavaScript:

```
String code="print(5+5);"; //sample bit of code
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("js");
try {
    engine.eval(code);
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    //catch statement
}
```

To run this, I imported the library `javax.script.*`. I believe to run PHP I would have to import a similar library, and change the third line of the code above to the extension `php`. Unfortunately, I don't know which library this is. I have Googled to try and find the answer, and came across the PHP/Java Bridge library but I don't think this is exactly what I'm looking for, as it is focussed on running Java through PHP (as far as I know).

I hope I haven't missed anything out, and any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/614995/calling-php-from-java) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @NickolayRatchev or Edmund, one of you should go ahead and write up an answer for this since you both seem t ohave figured it out.

Comment: @Edmund: You should post that as an answer, not as a comment. I went ahead and removed the "Update" section of your question, since it is in fact an answer to your own question

Comment: A more complete solution based on the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/q/40960138/243233

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to download the files `JavaBridge.jar`, `php-script.jar` and `php-servlet.jar` from http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/download.php then import them into your class:

```
import javax.script.*;

import php.java.bridge.*;
import php.java.script.*;
import php.java.servlet.*;
```

Then the code can then be run as before:

```
String code="echo 5+5;"; //sample bit of code
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByExtension("php");
try {
    engine.eval(code);
} catch (ScriptException ex) {
    //catch statement
}
```

Comment: The three imports:
import php.java.bridge.*;
import php.java.script.*;
import php.java.servlet.*;
are useless, no?

Comment: No, the `ScriptEngine` needs the three imports in order to run the PHP.

Comment: Gives a php not found error. Help?

Comment: How to read the output of php code (say if it returns of echos something)?

Comment: @EdmundGentle I don't want to start a new question since so many have been marked as duplicates but is this still possible? I've looked for about an hour now and I can't find `php-script.jar` anywhere on the internet. Is it s till required? Thanks.

Comment: @1Poseidon3 it looks as though they stopped using `php-script.jar` in v7. In [v6.2.3](https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-java-bridge/files/Binary%20package/php-java-bridge_6.2.3/exploded/) the file is in there. You may want to look at the docs to use the latest version.

Comment: @EdmundGentle Oh I didn't see that. I'll give it a look. Thank you.